# Why does pandas show delete rows in the groupby statment?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a simple pandas dataframe:

```
       A     B
0   test  fast
1  train  slow
2   test  fast
3  train  slow
```

Now I remove the rows where column A == test

```
df2.drop(df2[df2['A'] == 'test'].index, inplace=True)
```

And get as result:

```
       A     B
1  train  slow
3  train  slow
```

Now I run the groupby statement:

```
df2.groupby('A').B.count()
```

And get as result:

```
A
test     0
train    2
```

Why do I get a output for test although it was deleted ? 
How to avoid this ?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: I do not understand why pandas generate following line generated:
"test     0"

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dMATTg1B works fine, do recheck.

Comment: i did run your code it show me right answer as you want,

Comment: @SimonSander might be a bug that was already fixed in newer versions of pandas. What pandas version are you using? (you can check with print(pd.__version__))

Comment: @SimonSander you can check my explanation ~

Comment: @P.Tillmann it is not bug~just category dtype

Comment: @JohnGalt when the dtype is category will cause this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case , the data type of A is `category`, see below :

after converted A to category I got the same result with you

```
df.A=df.A.astype('category')
df1=df.drop(df[df['A'] == 'test'].index)
df1.groupby('A').B.count()

A
test     0
train    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

To get the output you want, just convert you original `df.A` to `string`:

```
df.A=df.A.astype('str')
df1=df.drop(df[df['A'] == 'test'].index)
df1.groupby('A').B.count()

Out[201]: 
A
train    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: hmm, it is interesting that this only happens for categorical. But the question remains if this behaviour is wanted or not.